# Qatar airways Baggage

Tags: air-travel, luggage, qatar-airways

The website had stated that checked baggage should not exceed 300cm in maximum dimension.

http://www.qatarairways.com/uk/en/baggage.page

Maximum dimension = length + width + height.

My luggage:

Height: 31"
Width: 14"
Length:22"

Would this be ok 
Flying from the UK to doha then delhi

Sorry I just want to make sure and not get sent back or get delayed or any other problem due to baggage

The website does say l + w + h it doesn't say l x w x h. So I worked it out and it did not exceed 118" but I just wanted to make sure I also emailed qatar airlines but they just told me to look at the website. Which I already did

Answer (score 5):

The maximum luggage dimension is 118 inches

In your case the luggage dimension is 67 inches. I do not see it being a problem unless it weighs more than 30 kg.

You will only face an overweight charge if it is more than 30 kg. (depends on the 'friendliness' of the person at the check-in counter)

However if it is more than 32 kg then you will have a problem because you will have to split the weight. Qatar Airways does not allow individual pieces of luggage more than 32 kg.

But since your question is about the dimensions; you don't have to worry about it. Why are you confused about it; it's already mentioned clearly on their website.

As a further check just confirm what's written on your itinerary.